# Usage of nested let or let* in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm writing a function taking an interval as an argument and returns the percentage error but I stuck in the usage of let or let*. Here's the code:

nested let version:

```
(define (percent interval)
  (let (start-point (car interval))
    (let (end-point (cdr interval))
      (let (center (/ (+ start-point end-point) 2)))))
  (/ (- end-point center) center))
```

the error is: let: bad syntax (not an identifier and expression for a binding) in: start-point

let* version:

```
(define (percent interval)
  (let* ((start-point (car interval))
     (end-point (cdr interval))
     (center (/ (+ start-point end-point) 2))))
  (/ (- end-point center) center))
```

the error now is:

```
let*: bad syntax (missing body) in: (let* ((start-point (car interval)) (end-point (cdr interval)) (center (/ (+ start-point end-point) 2))))
```

I've referred to some documentation but couldn't figure out the mistake as well. 
(ps: I'm using DrRacket 6.2)

Comment: You mention you're using DrRacket. Are you using the Racket language, one of the Scheme languages (R5RS or R6RS), or one of the teaching languages?

Comment: I'm using Scheme but isn't Racket a strict superset of Scheme?

Comment: Not quite, plus the various dialects are all a little different. It's just usually useful to specify *precisely* what variant of Scheme you're working with—none of them are quite the same.

Comment: Oh sorry I just noticed I was actually using Racket, which is specified by `#lang racket`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The final expression, the division itself, needs to go *inside* the `let*`. This is because `let` forms introduce bindings that are only lexically scoped to their bodies. Furthermore, `let` forms *require* a body, which is why you're getting that error (in your example, they have no body at all because the final expression is outside them).

To fix this, just move the final expression within the `let*` form:

```
(define (percent interval)
  (let* ((start-point (car interval))
         (end-point (cdr interval))
         (center (/ (+ start-point end-point) 2)))
    (/ (- end-point center) center)))
```

Your version using nested `let` is slightly wrong in another way: you're missing a level of parens for each binding pair, which is causing the first error. That is, instead of this:

```
(let (start-point (car interval))
  ...)
```

...you need this:

```
(let ((start-point (car interval)))
  ...)
```

Note the extra parentheses. That said, the `let*` version is much better! It's just a macro for nested `let` forms that does the nesting automatically so you don't have to.

One more thing: if you're writing portable Scheme, all the parentheses need to be parentheses. If you're writing Racket, though, you can use square brackets *interchangeably* with parentheses. Because of this, idiomatic Racket uses square brackets in certain places as a stylistic choice to make the code more readable.

One of these cases is in `let` binding pairs. Therefore, idiomatic Racket code would look like this:

```
(define (percent interval)
  (let* ([start-point (car interval)]
         [end-point (cdr interval)]
         [center (/ (+ start-point end-point) 2)])
    (/ (- end-point center) center)))
```

This just helps to make it more clear that each pair is creating a *binding* rather than calling a function.

Comment: Much thanks.Now I make it. In Racket nested let is surely much more complex than a let*, however in MIT Scheme in let structure the extra parentheses doesn't seek like indispensable.

Comment: Square brackets are the same as parentheses in R6RS Scheme so the idiomatic racket code is compatible.